# Consistent testing environment

Tags: windows, testing

I'm currently researching the performance of some DBMS's like MySQL, Oracle DB etc (not very important for this question).

What I try to do is to create a consistent environment for testing the different products in the same conditions. Is there a way / or some kind of software which can setup some kind of enviroment with minimal windows processes?

I hope the question is clear enough.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe look into a virtualization program like [VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/)?  This would allow you to install only what you need (e.g., a fresh copy of Windows + your minimum software requirements) and ensure consistency when testing a new DBMS or other products.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that.. I'm still hoping for a more specialized package for setting up a testing environment. (+1 but not yet accepted as the answer;))